# Maven build to include file in root folder of jar

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin, maven-resources-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I am using spring boot applications for my project. In one of the project, I need to include one config.properties file in the jar root path.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccP8b.png)
Because In my project, one of external jar is expecting this property file from file system, means root path of project.

```
propertieFile.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
```

Actually I am having this property file in eclipse maven project, but its ignored while build.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQeQw.png)
Can any one of you please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put it into src/main/resources as usual...

Answer (score -2):

Use the maven [standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). No further configuration is required if you use these directories, the files will be added in classpath.

For this kind of file is recomended to use the src/main/resources folder.

Using this you can use the classloader to input stream your file.

```
try (InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fullPath)) {
    propertieFile.load(is);
}
```

Comment: This does not resolved the issue. There are many of using cloud based applications which need the files at the root level.

Comment: @TonyEdwards yes, but the topic is asking about a config.properties inside a project/jar: "I am having this property file in eclipse maven project".